# C# - Timer ran by the callback of a thread only runs once

Tags: c#

So I'm running into a slight issue with my threads and timers in a C# application I'm working on, where a key timer only runs once.

This is the main function of the program where the initial thread gets started:

```
private static System.Threading.Timer timer;

static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => startAutoSpec(), null, 1000 * 5, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Thereafter in the startAutoSpec (below) function it runs the whole code (which I didn't see any need of adding) and this for all intents and purposes runs completely fine

```
public static void startAutoSpec() 
{
    if (noGamesFound) {
        timer.Dispose();
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => startAutoSpec(), null, 1000 * 60, Timeout.Infinite);
    } else 
    { 
        startSpectating(args here);
        timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now here is where we're hitting the main problem, with the timer initialized inside the startSpectating function. It only seems to run once.

```
public static void startSpectating(whatever args) 
{
    all the spectating related stuff
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
    {
        stillInGame(summoner.id.ToString(), region, gameid.ToString());
    }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
}
```

Which in turn runs this checker

```
public static void stillInGame(string sumId, string region, string gameId)
{
    checks that game is still active
    Console.WriteLine("Checking if still ingame...");
    if (game is finished) {
        close the game process
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => startAutoSpec(), null, 1000 * 60, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

So I figured I needed to provide the whole context for how the threads and timers work to best describe my issue. The stillInGame() function only runs once from the timer on the startSpectating() function and I'm not entirely sure why. Any ideas? Not sure if this post makes much sense either, so please tell me if I need to expand even more, thanks!

Comment: The 4th argument of the Timer constructor specifies the *period*, the delay between ticks.  You made it *infinite*, so correctly observed you got "only run once" behavior.  You then worked around it by re-creating the timer object repeatedly, but fumbled the one in startSpectating().  System.Threading.Timer is pretty tricky, a garbage collection can make it stop ticking when it sees no reference to the object.  Fwiw, using its Change() method is one way to ensure it stays alive for one tick.  But don't use Infinite to get ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method `startSpectating` you are not reassigning the static `timer` field. Instead you are creating a new variable `timer` inside that method which is eligible for garbage collection after the method exists and the variable loses scope. You probably meant to assign the new timer to the static `field` timer like you do in the other methods. If not create a new field and assign the new timer to it.

```
public static void startSpectating(whatever args) 
{
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) => ....
    // should be
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) => ....
```